# How to make objects move in pygame, without making the rendering slow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, graphics, pygame, multiprocessing

I am currently designing an app, using pygame in which I have a number of circles connected through lines, with numerical text written in them. These circles are green, blue and red in color, while the other things are black. Background is white. (Imagine it like a network graph)

**My Objective**: I am trying to get an animation running, in which the user selects the two circles (let us call them nodes) and I find out the shortest path between the sender node (green) to the receiver node (red). So in this animation, I am making another moving circle on top of the line (or edge) that connects the two adjacent nodes (these may be the intermediate nodes).

[image: for e.g, the circle moves from node 2 to node 11 here]

So far all good, here's the code of what I am doing:

```
def runPathAnimation(path, colortype):
    for i in range(len(path)-1):
        #Calculation of the center of the nodes
        x1, y1 = (gmd[path[i]].getNodePosition())[0], (gmd[path[i]].getNodePosition())[1]
        x2, y2 = (gmd[path[i+1]].getNodePosition())[0], (gmd[path[i+1]].getNodePosition())[1]
        #Get the slope
        m = (y1-y2)/(x1-x2) if x1 != x2 else 'undefined'
        if str(m) != 'undefined':
            c = y2-(m*x2)
            if m > 0.5 or (m <= -1 and m >= -1.5):
                for y in range(min(y1,y2),max(y1,y2)):
                    #using the equation of the line
                    x = int((y-c)/m)
                    #redrawEverything(path)                                     #OPTION 1
                    #TRY REDRAW LINE                                            #TODO
                    pyg.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), (x-10,y-10,20,20))   #OPTION 2
                    pyg.draw.circle(screen, colortype, (x,y), 10)               #Moving circle
                    pyg.display.update()                                        #Update Display
                    #NEED: Redraw!
            #The logic repeats....
            else:
                for x in range(min(x1,x2),max(x1,x2)):
                    y = int(m*x+c)
                    #redrawEverything(path)
                    #TRY REDRAW LINE
                    pyg.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), (x-10,y-10,20,20))
                    pyg.draw.circle(screen, colortype, (x,y), 10)
                    pyg.display.update()
                    #NEED: Redraw!
        else:
            cy = range(min(y1,y2),max(y1,y2))
            if y1 > y2:
                cy = reversed(cy)
            for y in cy:
                #redrawEverything(path)
                #TRY REDRAW LINE
                pyg.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), (x1-10,y-10,20,20))
                pyg.draw.circle(screen, colortype, (x1,y), 10)
                pyg.display.update()
                #NEED: Redraw!
```

**My Problem**: There is a lot of lag with my method of simply updating a circle with another position, without disturbing anything that it covers. I had 2 options in my mind:

1. *OPTION 1*: Update everything on the screen (of course it did not give me a good performance)
2. *OPTION 2*: Update only the portion of the screen, which is what actually used. However, even with this method, I am not able to achieve a good performance for screen updation. I would like to later add a feature to control the speed of the animation, which may have a speed faster than the maximum performance of my code right now!

As you can see, I do not have any `time.sleep()` as of now. I would like to increase the performance of my code and then be able to add `time.sleep()` for a more controlled animation. My current pygame application is already running in parallel to another process, which I implemented using `multiprocessing` library.

**Question**: How do I make it faster?

My python version: 3.7.0, pygame version: 1.9.6

PS: Sorry for the length of the question

Comment: Have you considered *pre-*rendering all the animation frames to surfaces?  It's probably all those calls to `update()` slowing it down.  Can you move these outside of their loops?

Comment: @Kingsley not really, because I need to show the updated version after every step for a smooth animation :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found a workaround! Basically, I am unable a make the code o any faster due to pygame's own rendering abilities, even HW mode isn't improving the speed much.

**Solution (more of a workaround):**

I have added a layer of waiting period in which pygame takes snapshots of the rendered screen and stores the image in a self created cache, without updating the screen. Later, I just have a smooth operable screen which can be used to see the animation.

Here's the code:

```
def runPathAnimation(path, colortype):
    index = 0
    images = []
    for i in range(len(path)-1):
        x1, y1 = (gmd[path[i]].getNodePosition())[0], (gmd[path[i]].getNodePosition())[1]
        x2, y2 = (gmd[path[i+1]].getNodePosition())[0], (gmd[path[i+1]].getNodePosition())[1]
        m = (y1-y2)/(x1-x2) if x1 != x2 else 'undefined'

        cx, cy = range(min(x1,x2),max(x1,x2)), range(min(y1,y2),max(y1,y2))
        if y1 > y2:
            cy = reversed(cy) 
        if x1 > x2:
            cx = reversed(cx)

        if str(m) != 'undefined':
            con = y2-(m*x2)
            if m > 0.5 or (m <= -1 and m >= -1.5):
                for y in cy:
                    ev = pyg.event.get()
                    x = int((y-con)/m)
                    images.append(loadpath(x,y,path,colortype,index))
                    index += 1
                    r = pyg.draw.rect(screen, colortype, (md.WIDTH_NETWORKPLOT-250,md.PLOT_AREA[1]+30,index/5,20), 2)
                    pyg.display.update(r)
            else:
                for x in cx:
                    ev = pyg.event.get()
                    y = int(m*x+con)
                    images.append(loadpath(x,y,path,colortype,index))
                    index += 1
                    r = pyg.draw.rect(screen, colortype, (md.WIDTH_NETWORKPLOT-250,md.PLOT_AREA[1]+30,index/5,20), 2)
                    pyg.display.update(r)
        else:
            for y in cy:
                ev = pyg.event.get()
                images.append(loadpath(x1,y,path,colortype,index))
                index += 1
                r = pyg.draw.rect(screen, colortype, (md.WIDTH_NETWORKPLOT-250,md.PLOT_AREA[1]+30,index/5,20), 2)
                pyg.display.update(r)
        print('Loading...'+str((i+1)/len(path)*100)+'%')

    runAnimation(images)

def runAnimation(images):
    animate = True
    img = 0
    print('Start!')
    while animate:
        ev = pyg.event.get()
        pyg.event.pump()
        keys = pyg.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pyg.K_LEFT]:
            img -= 1
            if img < 0:
                img = 0
        if keys[pyg.K_RIGHT]:
            img += 1
            if img >= len(images) - 2:
                img = len(images) - 2
        if keys[pyg.K_q]:
            animate = False
        screen.blit(images[img],(0,0))
        pyg.display.update((0, 0, md.WIDTH_NETWORKPLOT, md.PLOT_AREA[1]))
```

PS: In my code, `md.xxx` are the dimensions for my `matplotlib` and `pygame` screen.

**IMPORTANT:** This is just a workaround, ***not a solution!!***

Answer (score 0):

Try using 
`pygame.time.Clock().tick(**)`
This is a command that allows you to choose the FPS you want to run your program with, allowing you to increase your rendering speed. If you decide to use this, put an integer that represents the FPS where I wrote the asterisks.

Comment: Tried that, not much difference :(

Comment: @Prakhar Saxena what did you set the FPS to?

Comment: I tried 40,60,80 and 120. 40 made my animation slower, but 60, 80 and 120 had no difference. So I guess that it is already running at a maximum. Although, I tried to switch to full screen mode, for using the hardware graphics, that did not improve my performance as well. Not sure what to do... @GalacticAvenger